# docker works only in the Quickstart Docker Terminal

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-machine

I have Windows 10 64 bit and when I use docker on the Quickstart Docker Terminal all works, but when I use it on Node.js command prompt or on the Windows Command Prompt docker doesn't work because it doesn't find an IP.

For example when I write "docker-machine ls" on the Quickstart Docker Terminal the following appears:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.11.1
dev       -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.103:2376           v1.11.1
```

But when I write that on the Node.js command prompt:

```
C:\Users\michele>docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running                 Unknown   Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 1
output  : command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: ControlMaster


dev   *    virtualbox   Running             Unknown   Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 1
output  : command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: ControlMaster
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Check the PATH in each instance. the one used by Nodejs probably interfer with the ssh bundled with docker.

Comment: Ah ok... and how I can check the path?